# What is the complexity of the next grammar

Tags: algorithm, parsing, notation, catalan

I'm developing a Generalized Parsing Algorithm and I'm testing it with next rule

```
S ::= a | SS
```

Well, the algorithm is showing me all trees generated for the string composed of `n a`'s.

For example next table shows the time used by the algorithm due to the quantity of `a`'s

```
length  trees   time(ms)
1           1   1
2           1   1
3           2   2
4           5   2
5           14  2
6           42  2
7           132 5
8           429 13
9           1430    28
10          4862    75
11          16796   225
12          58786   471
13          208012  1877
14          742900  10206
```

I dont know what `O` (Big O notation) is my algorithm. How can i measure it because of course the time depends of three things:

1. The length of the string to parse
2. The grammar complexity
3. The performance of the algorithm

Comment: [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is better for whiteboard problems (such as Big-O analysis). Make sure you post enough of the algorithm to analyse.

Answer (score 1):

S can match any string of all a's.

Any binary tree with n leaf nodes could be a parse tree, and the number of such trees is given by the [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Answer (score 0):

Big-O isn't a matter of measuring run-times; that's profiling. Big-O is a matter of algorithm analysis, which is impossible without seeing the algorithm.

Broadly speaking, break the algorithm down into basic operations, loops and recursive calls. The basic operations have a defined timing (generally, O(1)). The timing of loops is the number of iterations times the timing of the loop body. Recursion is trickier: you have to define the timing in terms of a recurrence relation, then solve for an explicit solution. Looking at the [process call tree](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.2) can offer hints as to what the explicit solution might be.

Comment: Well, it's possible to know the behavior of an algorithm by the graph it shows in many runnings (number of elements vs time or operations) and this algorithm is kind of exponential and i dont like it

Comment: @yuryeuceda: that's profiling, not Big-O, since it's only for specific inputs and may only represent best case, average case or worse case. Big-O is the result of analysis, not measurement.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the complexity neither because you didn't post the algorithm. But obviously there is a chance that you have an implementation that blows up pretty bad. The problem is not necessarily in the algorithm, thought, but in the grammar itself. A suitable preprocessor for the grammar could rewrite it to the more natural form

```
S ::= a | a S
```

which would be much more efficient to handle.

Comment: Of course! but in this way i'm changing the meaning and remember i'm trying to create an algorithm and i think this is very slow approach because is growing too much